# Dojo Mobile Scrollableview : How to animate and scroll to top?

Tags: dojo, dojox.mobile

```
    require(["dojox/mobile/parser", "dijit/registry", "dojo/domReady!"], function(parser, registry) {
        var view = registry.byId("myId");
        view.scrollTo({x:0 ,y: 0});
    });
```

The above piece of code scrolls to the top. But there is no animation.
Any suggestion how to animate and scroll to top?

Comment: Take a look at the [Scrollable view](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/mobile/ScrollableView.html) widget provided by dojo.

Comment: There is nothing related to animating the scrollable view.

Comment: can you explain more on the animation stuff that you require? You requirement is not clear. Do you want to animate within the view or do you require animation when you move from one view to another view?

Comment: currently with the above code, there is no scroll effect when the page moves to the top. It just takes me to the top at one shot. I need the dojo mobile scrollableview to scroll and more to top @frank

Comment: Can you provide the equivalent in dojo for this
` $('#view').animate({scrollTop: 150},'slow');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [slideTo()](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dojox/mobile/ScrollableView#1_10dojox_mobile_ScrollableView_slideTo) method provided by scrollableView.